# SQL Server Transactional Replication snapshot delivery loop

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I have configured transactional replication from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2014. And everything is OK, except one thing: after the initial snapshot is delivered to subscriber, distribution agent starts to deliver it again, the same articles in the same order, instead of applying undistribution transactions, pending delivery.

[image: replication]

I tried to reinitialize subscription, re-create subscription and generate new snapshot, but it doesn't help.
There are no any errors in any of agents history, but snapshot delivery is just looped.

How can it be fixed?

Comment: So, by some reasons it was happened because triggers and non-clustered indexes were included in replication. After they were excluded the snapshot delivery didn't loop anymore. And after snapshot was delivered, I just created all missing indexes and triggers manually on the subscriber as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, by some reasons it was happened because triggers and non-clustered indexes were included in replication. After they were excluded the snapshot delivery didn't loop anymore. And after snapshot was delivered, I just created all missing indexes and triggers manually on the subscriber as a workaround.